# Tuples as Dictionary value

Tags: swift, dictionary, xcode6

My problem is: I have a dictionary with a enum type as key and a named tuple as value.

```
private let positionDictionary:[Position:(shortG: String, longG: String, shortE: String, longE: String)] =
[   .Goalkeeper:("TW","Torwart","GK","Goalkeeper"),
    .CentralDefender:("IV","Innenverteidiger","CD","Central Defender"),
    .LeftBack:("LV","Linker Verteidiger","LB","Left Back"),
    .LeftWingBack:("LAV","Linker Außenverteidiger","LWB","Left Wing Back"),
    .RightBack:("RV","Rechter Verteidiger","RB","Right Back"),
    .RightWingBack:("RAV","Rechter Außenverteidiger","RWB","Right Wing Back")]
```

This is part of class where I want to do this:

```
self.positionDictionary[.Goalkeeper].shortE
```

But the compiler tells me that he "could not find the member 'shortE'". What am I missing? I would really much appreciate any help :]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dictionary key subscript returns optional values. You need to unwrap it or use optional bidding:

```
if let goalkeepersShortE = self.positionDictionary[.Goalkeeper]?.shortE {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: or `self.positionDictionary[.Goalkeeper]!.shortE`

Comment: do not use previous comment. if the dictionary containts no value for key .Goalkeeper it will crash at runtime. always check your optionals.